# Question in integral curve

Tags: differential-geometry

[image]
 Can anybody please help me by explaining why they have evaluated $x_1(t)$ and $x_2(t)$ at $0$.

Last second expression where they found $/alpha(t)$.

Answer (score 1):

This is a somewhat arbitrary choice. Any change of parameter $t \mapsto t -c $ with $c$ a constant will solve the same differential equation, just with different start points. So usually, when one is looking for a curve departing in some point $p$, one chooses the one which takes on that value for $t=0$.